# Removing Multiple Ifs in with inequality conditions

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

I am trying to convert this code into less bulky format, I know we can remove ifs by using dictionary but that goes only when you have equality, If you are looking for some range check, what should be the alternative.
My code is as follows:

```
def dispersion(x):
   v = float(x) / 100
   if v <= -.20:
     return '< -20%'
   elif -.20 < v <= -.10:
     return '-20% to -10%'
   elif -.10 < v <= -0.05:
     return '-10% to -5%'
   elif -.05 < v <= .0:
     return '-5% to 0%'
   elif 0 < v <= .05:
     return '0% to 5%'
   elif .05 < v <= .10:
     return '5% to 10%'
   elif .10 < v <= .20:
     return '10% to 20%'
   else:
     return '> 20%'
```

P.S- I was thinking of using binary search , but not able to formulate into the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use `bisect` (returns insertion index in an ordered list using binary search), and after adjusting the edge cases a working code looks like this (note that you don't have to divide by 100, just keep everything as integers, it's easier for the display):

```
import bisect

def dispersion(x):
    values = [-20,-10,-5,0,5,10,20]
    i = bisect.bisect(values,x)
    if i==0:
        return '< {}%'.format(values[0])
    elif i==len(values):
        return '>= {}%'.format(values[-1])
    else:
        return '{}% to {}%'.format(values[i-1],values[i])
```

testing that in a -50,50 range:

```
for i in range(-50,50,10):
    print(i,dispersion(i))
```

result:

```
-50 < -20%
-40 < -20%
-30 < -20%
-20 -20% to -10%
-10 -10% to -5%
0 0% to 5%
10 10% to 20%
20 >= 20%
30 >= 20%
40 >= 20%
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this?

def dispersion(x):
      if x < -20:
        return '< -20%'

```
  lowerBound = 20
  for upperBound in [-10, -5, 0, 5, 10, 20]:
    if lowerBound < x <= upperBound:
      return str(lowerBound) + "% to " + str(upperBound) + "%"
    upperBound = lowerBound

  return '> 20%'
```

The strings for `< -20` and `> 20` is dissimilar enough from the other strings that they kinda have to have their own condition check. The other ones can definitely be checked in a range.

Some notes, though:

Is there any real reason to convert to floats? Comparing the initial integer `x` should be sufficient. (If it's another type, cast it to an int).

Because you are returning from each `if` statement, there is no need to do `elif` and `else`. This is functionally the same:

```
if condition1:
  return 1
if condition2: # equivalent to `elif condition2`
  return 2
if condition3: # equivalent to `elif condition3`
  return 3
return other # equivalent to `else`
```

After removing `elif` and `else` and the float conversion, I feel as though your original code would be cleaner and easier to read than the ranged version. But that' subjective.